# Other than class, id and text, how else can I pass a variable within an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, variables

I have a situation where class and id are taken, but I need to pass a variable in jQuery.  How do you recommend?

HTML

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="cannot_change_this"
    class="rather_not_append_extra_classes_just_for_a_variable"
    value="Full Text Name"
    hash="ABCDE">
```

Each value, when selected via autocomplete has an associated hash.  In the example above the value might be `Full Text Name`, but this is not unique.  What I really need to pass is the hash: `ABCDE`.

I can't change the id and I'd rather not add extra classes and have to filter out the ones used for styles to get my hash.  And since it's an `input` I can't use .text() either.

How else can I pass `ABCDE` hash to jQuery?

Comment: Please show the hash structure.

Comment: It's actually closer to a slug of the value (full-text-name), but it's a unique value and can't be derived from the value since it might also be something like `full-text-name-2`.

Comment: Oh. so you need to calculate the data and put in into the source output rather than setting it via javascript? You should look at the HTML5 data properties mentioned in my answer below.  Then again if you don't care about being compliant, you can simply add your own property like `hash=HASH` to the element and read it from jQuery like `$('input#id').attr('hash')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using jQuery's data method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

You can calculate the hash of the value in javascript, then set it to the input's data.

Also if using HTML5, you can specifically declare data attributes in the HTML.  So you could use a property like `data-hash=HASH` to set your data.

Alternatively, if you don't care about comliance or maybe you aren't using HTML5, you could just set your own attribute like

```
<input type="text" id="cannot_change_this"
class="rather_not_append_extra_classes_just_for_a_variable" 
value="Full Text Name" hash="ABCDE" />
```

And read it with jQuery like this:

```
var hash = $('input#idOfInput').attr('hash');
```

Comment: So something like: <input type="text" id="sampleId" class="sampleClass" value="Full Text Name" data-hash="ABCDE">

Answer (score 1):

If i got it right.

Setting the value:

```
$("#cannot_change_this").data("hash", hashValue);
```

Getting the value later:

```
$("#cannot_change_this").data("hash");
```

Comment: What would this look like on the input tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the title attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="cannot_change_this"
class="rather_not_append_extra_classes_just_for_a_variable" 
value="Full Text Name"title="ABCDE" />
```

it is a standard attribute for all inputs.

Comment: This is probably a better solution than defining a 'hash' attribute as I have mentioned if you do not need to use the title for other concerns (like accessibility) and aren't using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//SET:
 jQuery("#cannot_change_this").attr("new-value", "ABCDE");
//READ:
 var val = jQuery("#cannot_change_this").attr("new-value");
 alert(val);
 });
```